# Execute an Uninstall-Setup from server on remote computers via PowerShell

Tags: powershell

This is my first question here and I am also quite new on PowerShell, so I hope I am doing everything alright.

My problem is the following: I want to uninstall a programm on several computers, check if the registry-key is deleted and then install a new version of the programm.

The setup is located on a server within the same domain as the computers.

I want my Script to loop through the computers and execute the setup from the server for every computer. As I am quite new with PowerShell, I have no idea how to do this. I was thinking to maybe use Copy-Item, but I dont want to really move the setup, but simply execute it from the server to the computers? Any idea how to do this?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following approach.

Note that the need to provide credentials explicitly is a workaround for the infamous [double-hop problem](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ashleymcglone/2016/08/30/powershell-remoting-kerberos-double-hop-solved-securely/).

```
# The list of computers on which to run the setup program.
$remoteComputers = 'computer1', 'computer2' # ...

# The full UNC path of the setup program.
$setupExePath = '\\server\somepath\setup.exe'

# Obtain credentials that can be used on the
# remote computers to access the share on which 
# the setup program is located.
$creds = Get-Credential

# Run the setup program on all remote computers.
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $remoteComputers {

    # WORKAROUND FOR THE DOUBLE-HOP PROBLEM:
    # Map the target network share as a dummy PS drive using the passed-through
    # credentials.
    # You may - but needn't - use this drive; the mere fact of having established
    # a drive with valid credentials makes the network location accessible in the
    # session, even with direct use of UNC paths.
    $null = New-PSDrive -Credential $using:cred dummy -Root (Split-Path -Parent $using:$setupExePath) -PSProvider FileSystem

    # Invoke the setup program from the UNC share.
    & $using:$setupExePath

    # ... do other things

}
```